# Configure Filebeat hints-based Autodiscover with Elastic Common Schema

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, elastic-common-schema

I'm can't find any documentation on how to configure filebeat to handle ECS formatted JSON logs.

I'm using [ecs-pino-format](https://github.com/elastic/ecs-logging-js/tree/master/loggers/pino) to output "ECS" logs and here is a typical log I output :

```
{"log":{"level":"debug","logger":"pino"},"@timestamp":"2020-06-10T17:02:11.266Z","module":"APM","ecs":{"version":"1.5.0"},"message":"ended transaction {\"trans\":\"7614bf8a4895a7a4\",\"trace\":\"8a5c71d2c1c63f6dfc1a5bfd046701ed\",\"type\":\"request\",\"result\":\"HTTP 2xx\",\"name\":\"GET /healthcheck\"}"}
```

Here is my filebeat configuration :

```yaml
filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
        - type: kubernetes
          node: ${NODE_NAME}
          hints.enabled: true
          hints.default_config:
            type: container
            paths:
              - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log
```

With this config, my logs are not interpreted by Kibana : 
[image]

I add this annotation to my pod (not even sure I must do this...):

```yaml
co.elastic.logs/json.keys_under_root: true
```

This is the error I have on filebeat :

```
2020-06-10T16:47:00.773Z    WARN    [elasticsearch]    elasticsearch/client.go:384    Cannot index event publisher.Event{Content:beat.Event{Timestamp:time.Time{wall:0x304e23a, ext:63727404418, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}, Meta:null, Fields:{"agent":{"ephemeral_id":"cc9f9def-5d67-4592-8459-f556f8f2fc29","hostname":"filebeat-filebeat-4dqpq","id":"e8d9cffe-ceca-49f5-ae31-65bbb29353e8","type":"filebeat","version":"7.7.0"},"ecs":{"version":"1.5.0"},"host":{"name":"filebeat-filebeat-4dqpq"},"input":{"type":"container"},"json":{"@timestamp":"2020-06-10T16:46:58.049Z","ecs":{"version":"1.5.0"},"log":"","message":"sending span {\"span\":\"87ad75b7f0858817\",\"parent\":\"82e1f82870aa3e55\",\"trace\":\"13c7569f7562a72bef1300097d1ab86c\",\"name\":\"SELECT\",\"type\":\"db\"}","module":"APM","trace.id":"13c7569f7562a72bef1300097d1ab86c","transaction.id":"82e1f82870aa3e55"},"kubernetes":{"container":{"image":"registry.gitlab.com/consensys/codefi/products/assets/workflow-api:v0.1.3-2-g358bbc6","name":"generic-app"},"labels":{"app_kubernetes_io/instance":"workflow-api","app_kubernetes_io/name":"workflow-api","pod-template-hash":"b946b7c49"},"namespace":"codefi","node":{"name":"ip-192-168-33-94.eu-west-3.compute.internal"},"pod":{"name":"workflow-api-b946b7c49-7qldb","uid":"e984519d-8cc5-426d-bdac-e3f0dfa55c0b"},"replicaset":{"name":"workflow-api-b946b7c49"}},"log":{"file":{"path":"/var/log/containers/workflow-api-b946b7c49-7qldb_codefi_generic-app-9bff78b56f893e056e1e614de3c28aa6671dd4723c0dfc166460ac9bde43571a.log"},"offset":2303955},"stream":"stdout"}, Private:file.State{Id:"", Finished:false, Fileinfo:(*os.fileStat)(0xc000ac8a90), Source:"/var/log/containers/workflow-api-b946b7c49-7qldb_codefi_generic-app-9bff78b56f893e056e1e614de3c28aa6671dd4723c0dfc166460ac9bde43571a.log", Offset:2304478, Timestamp:time.Time{wall:0xbfb060a48062556d, ext:986606661848, loc:(*time.Location)(0x3bdbf40)}, TTL:-1, Type:"container", Meta:map[string]string(nil), FileStateOS:file.StateOS{Inode:0x601c938, Device:0x10301}}, TimeSeries:false}, Flags:0x1, Cache:publisher.EventCache{m:common.MapStr(nil)}} (status=400): {"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"object mapping for [json.log] tried to parse field [log] as object, but found a concrete value"
```

If I remove the annotation, I don't see any error, so I guess it comes from this configuration.

Did I miss some docs here ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Found it. For future reference, when using ECS log format and hints-based autodiscover, simply add these annotations to your pods :

```
co.elastic.logs/json.keys_under_root: true
co.elastic.logs/json.message_key: message
co.elastic.logs/json.overwrite_keys: true
```

I hope this can help others !

Comment: I have used below configuration 
providers:
          - hints.default_config:
              paths:
                - '/var/log/containers/*-${data.container.id}.log'
              type: container
            hints.enabled: true
            host: '${HOSTNAME}'
   
and annotation 
co.elastic.logs/fileset= access

to get all container/pods logs to see in elastic search

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in 2022, the annotations above didn't work, I  found a [blog](https://cassiomolin.com/2019/06/30/log-aggregation-with-spring-boot-elastic-stack-and-docker/) talking about logging in elastic using docker that inspired me, and this is what I did:

```yaml
filebeat.autodiscover:
 providers:
   - type: kubernetes
     node: ${NODE_NAME}
     hints.enabled: true
     hints.default_config:
       type: container
       paths:
         - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log


processors:
  # - add_cloud_metadata:
  # - add_host_metadata:
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["message"]
      process_array: false
      max_depth: 3
      target: ""
      overwrite_keys: true
      add_error_key: true
      expand_keys: true
#...
```

I added the processor above to extract fields from the "message" field. Hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

I have used below configuration
providers:
- hints.default_config:
paths:
- '/var/log/containers/*-${data.container.id}.log'
type: container
hints.enabled: true
host: '${HOSTNAME}'

and annotation
co.elastic.logs/fileset= access

to get all container/pods logs to see in elastic search